# XML xpath attribute value result to contain other results

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xpath, simplexml

I recently asked a question about how to select a parent's node attribute and its values at the same time *using  xpath*, What i ended up with is :

```
Parent/@attr|Parent/x
```

It grab the parent `attr`'s value and all of its `x`'s nodes..

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [attr] => attrValue
                )
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

)
```

The thing now.. In case there are several `Parent` nodes, it will mix them together and i wouldn't know which `attr` belongs to its `x`'s .. it will result something like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [attr] => attrValue
                )
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [attr] => anotherAttrValue
                )
        )

    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    ...
)
```

You see, they are all treated as a normal result,  **what i am trying to do**  is to make the `attr` contain all of it's results ( 1, 2, 3 ) in an array or something and the same thing goes to the other `attr`'s to end up with something like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [attr] => attrValue
                )
        )
        Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 3
                )
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [attr] => anotherAttrValue
                )
        )
        Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 3
                )
        )
)
```

using the xpath and the way given at first

Comment: I believe previous answers pointed at xslt, I suspect the crowd was correct to point you in that direction.
What is it you're trying to achieve? "What's the XPath..." doesn't seem like the right question to ask in the first place
Are you trying to produce one file from another or parse the XML in  code or...?

Comment: @StenPetrov I'm trying to find from where did the `x`'s results came from or which `attr` do they belong to, read the question again

Comment: I'm asking about the context of the task, not the task itself.